# Infinite loop Recursive Search

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
SearchResultType<T> recursive_binary_search(const std::vector<T> &list,const T &value){
    long int low = 0;
    long int high = list.size() - 1;
    long int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

    if (low != high) {
        if (value < list[mid]) {
            std::vector<T> sub(&list[low], &list[mid - 1]);
            return recursive_binary_search(sub, value);
        }
        else if (value > list[mid]) {
            std::vector<T> sub(&list[mid + 1], &list[high]);
            return recursive_binary_search(sub, value);
        }
        else if (value == list[mid]) {
            return SearchResultType<T>(true, value, mid);
        }
    }
    else {
        return SearchResultType<T>(false, list[mid], mid);
    }
}
```

When I am using this code to search a string inside a vector it gets stuck in a infinite loop.Any idea why it is getting stuck?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this. For every iteration of the loop, a new vector gets constructed, containing a subset of the original vector being recursed into? I very strongly doubt that this is how to you were taught to do a binary search. Even if you find and fix the bug, you will fail this assignment.

Comment: Just a quick hint, when you have something where two things are moving towards each other and you want to stop when they meet, don't use `==`, use `<` or `>` (depending on which is appropriate).  This handles the case where they actually went past each other as well as if they met in the middle.  In your code, instead of `if (low != high) {`, use `low < high`  It'll save you from many of the dreaded off-by-one errors.

Comment: Please add the necessary code to it a [mcve]. Without that, it is too much work for SO users to figure out the input values for which the program fails.

Comment: Consider what happens when you're searching a list of length 2 and the value comes before the first element.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik assignments are not always graded for efficiency; in beginning classes in particular correctness is often the main criterion, followed by readability.  (efficiency would only be considered if the efficiency were so bad that the program failed to terminate in a reasonable amount of time)